# Failed to send email using gmail as client (django, graphene)

Tags: django, graphql, gmail

I am trying to set up email client to be gmail in my django project. When i register a user it gives me the following error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "register": {
      "success": false,
      "errors": {
        "nonFieldErrors": [
          {
            "message": "Failed to send email.",
            "code": "email_fail"
          }
        ]
      },
      "token": null
    }
  }
}
```

My settings.py looks like this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "youremail@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "yourpassword"
```

I have already enabled 2 step authentication with google.

My AuthMutation looks like this:

```
class AuthMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    register = mutations.Register.Field()
    verify_account = mutations.VerifyAccount.Field()
    login = mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    update_account = mutations.UpdateAccount.Field()
    resend_activation_email = mutations.ResendActivationEmail.Field()
    send_password_reset_email = mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail.Field()
    password_reset = mutations.PasswordReset.Field()
    password_change = mutations.PasswordChange.Field()
```

Thanks in advance to the amazing stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to GRAPHQL_AUTH:

```
'EMAIL_FROM':'youremail@gmail.com',
```